# Not able to merge init.mp4 and seg-*.m4s with ffmpeg and python due to its file format difference

Tags: python, ffmpeg, merge, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm developing video downloader (only for free videos) for korean anime streaming site https://laftel.net/

I guess laftel.net uses mpeg-dash for their streaming.
I found "init.mp4" file and "segments-number.m4s" files in chrome developer tools.

Code below downloads seg-1.m4s (name of the first segment) to seg-239.m4s (name of the last segment) file and init.mp4 file and it works.

```
(Skip the beginning becasue there is a code that collects "Request-URL" for each .m4s files in network stream)


#variable "found" is part of the "Request-URL"

def curl_m4s():
    for i in range(1,240): #number of the .m4s segment file is constant at 239
        vid_url = f"https://mediacloud.laftel.net/{found}/video/avc1/2/seg-{i}.m4s"
        aud_url = f"https://mediacloud.laftel.net/{found}/audio/mp4a/eng/seg-{i}.m4s"
        
        if i < 10: #for single digit num
            os.system(f"curl {vid_url} > {location}/vids/vid00{i}.m4s")
            os.system(f"curl {aud_url} > {location}/auds/aud00{i}.m4s")
            sleep(random.randint(1,3))
            
        elif i < 100: #for double digit num
            os.system(f"curl {vid_url} > {location}/vids/vid0{i}.m4s")
            os.system(f"curl {aud_url} > {location}/auds/aud0{i}.m4s")
            sleep(random.randint(1,3))
            
        else: #for three digit num
            os.system(f"curl {vid_url} > {location}/vids/vid{i}.m4s")
            os.system(f"curl {aud_url} > {location}/auds/aud{i}.m4s")
            sleep(random.randint(1,3))

location = os.getcwd()

os.system(f"curl https://mediacloud.laftel.net/{found}/video/avc1/2/init.mp4 > {location}/vids/vid_init.mp4")
os.system(f"curl https://mediacloud.laftel.net/{found}/audio/mp4a/eng/init.mp4 > {location}/auds/aud_init.mp4")
os.system(f"curl https://mediacloud.laftel.net/{found}/stream.mpd > {location}/stream.mpd")

curl_m4s()
#use curl in cmd and downloads each of the .m4s (001 ~ 239)
```

So in the vids folder i have "init.mp4" for video and "seg-1.m4s ~ seg-239.m4s" for video
and in the auds folder i have "init.mp4" for audio and "seg-1.m4s ~ seg-239.m4s" for audio

Problem is, I cannot merge init file and segment files.
I have no idea about combining .mp4 and .m4s together.
There are a lot of example codes for merging init.m4s + seg-*.m4s but I couldn't find init.mp4 + seg-*.mp4 codes.

I tried to merge segments together first, like this and it works.

```
location = os.getcwd()

os.system(f"cd {location}")
os.system("copy /b vid*.m4s vid_full.m4s")
```

and now, i want to merge init.mp4 becasue it has very much information about whole video files.
But how??

I tried these and none of them worked (looks like Successfull merge but it do not contain any watchable video)

```
# vid_full is merged segment files (seg-1.m4s + ... + seg-239.m4s)
 
1. 
os.system("copy /b init.mp4 + vid*.m4s video_full.m4s")
os.system("ffmpeg -i video_full.m4s -c:a copy video_full.mp4")


2. 
os.system("type vid_init.mp4 index.txt > Filename.mp4")


3. 
import os 

os.system("ffmpeg -i vid_full.m4s -c:a copy vid_full.mp4")
os.system("copy /b vid_init.mp4 + vid_full.mp4 VIDEO.mp4")
```

All problem occurs the format of the init file is .mp4. If it was .m4s I guess I could merge it.

and I guess i must merge init file and segments files together both in .m4s format. Is it right?
Via ffmpeg, i couldn't encode init.mp4 to init.m4s so this is the problme also.

So, Please help me merge init.mp4 and segments.m4s

All methods are wellcome at least it is based on python.

1. I tried to merge init.mp4 + merged_segment.m4s but it failed
2. I tried to convert init.mp4 to init.m4s via ffmpeg but it failed
3. I tried to convert all the segments to .mp4 files and merge into init.mp4 but it failed

I want to merge init file and segment files and make playable video.
Pleas Teach me how to do this.

Links below are what I used for my test :

[Laftel.net URL]
https://laftel.net/player/40269/46123

[Request URL for init.mp4 (video)]
https://mediacloud.laftel.net/2021/04/46773/v15/video/dash/video/avc1/2/init.mp4

[Request URL for init.mp4 (audio)]
https://mediacloud.laftel.net/2021/04/46773/v15/video/dash/audio/mp4a/eng/init.mp4

[Request URL for seg-1.m4s (video)]
https://mediacloud.laftel.net/2021/04/46773/v15/video/dash/video/avc1/2/seg-1.m4s

[Request URL for seg-1.m4s (audio)]
https://mediacloud.laftel.net/2021/04/46773/v15/video/dash/audio/mp4a/eng/seg-1.m4s

Comment: **(1)** MP4, M4V, M4A, M4S, 3GP are all **variations** of the **same file format** (_eg:_ M4A is just a signal that it's an MP4 without a video track inside those bytes). **(2)** It should be enough to take `init.mp4` as the starting bytes and then at its ending, just join the bytes of `seg-1.m4s` followed by `seg-2.m4s` etc etc... **(3)** Make sure you are downloading bytes as **binary** data and not as maybe, UTF text **string** etc. **(4)** Finally provide a download link to your testable "init.mp4" and "seg-1.m4s" files for advice about why your input is not giving a working file.

Comment: **First of all, thank you so much for your responding my question!**
Your comment was very helpful.

**I added the URL and Request-URL for the test** (same what I used for my test) **in the end of the question.**


You adviced me "It should be enough to take init.mp4 as the starting bytes and then at its ending, just join the bytes of seg-1.m4s followed by seg-2.m4s etc etc... "
I understood what you mean roughly.. But **what method** should I take **specifically**?

Comment: @VC.One

**(1)** `copy /b .\vid\init.mp4+.\vid\*.m4s  vid_full.m4s` and `ffmpeg -i vid_full.m4s -c:a copy video.mp4`
**(2)** `copy /b .\vid\init.mp4+.\video\*.m4s  vid_full.mp4` and `ffmpeg -i vid_full.mp4 -c:a copy video.mp4`
**(3)** `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vid_index.txt -c copy vid_full.mp4` and `ffmpeg -i vid_full.mp4 -c:a copy video.mp4`
*vid_index.txt is a list that contains init.mp4 and segments file name 1 to 239.

Is there any available method out of this? or could you teach me another right way?

**Much appreciate for your reading and commenting my questions. Thanks!**

Comment: I checked your files. Video's Seg-1.mp4 is **encrypted** (with [Shaka packager](https://developers.google.com/widevine/open-source/shaka-packager)) and that's why joining `init` and  `seg-1` parts together does not make a playable file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not really sure I can decrypt it but I will try it. Again, **thanks a lot.**